# Distance of $n$ points in a circle from a variable point

Tags: geometry

Consider a unit circle and n given points $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ in the circle.For any variable  point P in the circle ,What is the average of the distances $PA_1,PA_2,\dots,PA_n$?Can we find the bounds for this average and can it be equal to radial distance of the point $P$ for any point in the circle?Lots of thanks for any help\hints

Comment: It seems to me that the upper bound would be achieved when all $A_1$, $\dots$, $A_n$ are on the circumference of the circle? Note also that in the above scenario, the distribution of the $n$ distances are independent and identical to one another, so you can just figure out the answer by computing the answer for the case when there is only $A_1$, and then multiply it by $n$.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskLinePicking.html) the distribution of the distances $x$ between the points is given by

$$P(x) = \frac{4x} \pi \arccos \left( \frac x 2 \right) - \frac{2x^2} \pi \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2} 4}$$

so for $n \to \infty$ the average approaches $\frac{128}{45 \pi} \approx 0.905$